# How do I fix this "<name> is declared but never used" error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool GameHasEnded = false;

    public void EndGame()
    {
        if (GameHasEnded == false)
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", 2);
            Debug.Log("LOSER!!!  you DUMB");
            
        }


    void Restart()
        {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the error: "cs8321  restart is declared but never used". Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error is saying you've created a *local* function and are not using it. "local" is the important part of the error. The solution is to move the `Restart` function to the `GameManager` class rather than where it is *inside* the `EndGame` function.

Comment: Judging by the indenting, you might be missing a `}` to end the `EndGame` method.

Answer (score 0):

From Retired Ninja's comment:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool GameHasEnded = false;

    public void EndGame()
    {
        if (GameHasEnded == false)
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", 2);
            Debug.Log("LOSER!!!  you DUMB");                
        }   
    }

    void Restart()
    {
       SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```